# Database or application lock-file

Tags: java, database

To guarantee only a single write-transaction per database/resource I'm creating a .lock-file which prevents other JVMs from starting a session.

However, I'm not sure how it is handled for instance in Eclipse if the Application crashed. I think I had to remove the file manually?! So, is this a common solution or do other solutions exist? I think a restarted application (after a crash) cannot be distinguished from a usual application, I think that is one thing which bothered me once or twice with Eclipse, which didn't show up a proper message that I had to delete the lock-file before restarting Eclipse. But I'm not really sure if that was the problem.

Ok, I might have another solution for write transactions which have to check for a transaction-log which is deleted for proper commited transactions. But well, the write-transaction is ussed *after* the check. Do other solutions exist? I can't think of any...

Comment: 99% of commercial databases ensure read/write consistency, you most likely do not need to implement this. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm developing a simple versioned tree-structured storage system (open source, which soon also offers XQuery/XQuery Update Facility mechanisms) especially suitable for flash-based storage (Snapshot Isolation through a kind of MVCC (versioning) and several well known versioning strategies. I know that something on top of a relational database system is the easiest way, but most probably not as flexible as such a tailored solution.

Answer (score 1):

Databases have been handling transactions and isolation for a long time.  I cannot for the life of me see why you'd see the need to reinvent this wheel.  Have you not heard of JTA?

Have a look at Spring and its transaction managers.  This problem has been solved better by others.

UPDATE:  NoSQL means no ACID by design.  If you need ACID, don't use NoSQL.  You're adding complexity to make up for a poor design decision.

What does Eclipse have to do with this?  It's an IDE.  I presume that your users won't have to fire up an IDE to run your app.

Comment: Sure, it seems Apache Derby also just creates a lock-file (at least depending on the configuration and so does Eclipse to prevent other JVMs from accessing the workspace) which in some situations must be deleted by hand. Yes, I know, it was inappropriate comparing it with NoSQL databases, but nontheless. Consistency wouldn't be guaranteed cause of not isolating the transaction (and the database would eventually be corrupted in the worst case, at least in my current design with only one allowed write-transaction in parallel to n read-transactions).

Answer (score 0):

You should really try and dodge this bullet.

But if you are using a dbms with the ability to use transactions back in the old days, this was one trick for application or user locks

You create a table e.g applicationLocks
Then you start a transaction and insert / update a specific record, but do not commit it.
Anyone else coming in after won't be able to because the row is locked, and you take some suitable action.

When the application closes, rollback.

If the application crashes, the connection will get closed and the transaction rolled back anyway.

Comment: I can't dodge this bullet ;-) I'm developing a simple open source versioned, treebased storage system (through MVCC and a suitable paging-structure) and most implementations (XML databases, NoSQL databases) I've seen do not really support ACID safe transactions (nor do I currently). But it would be one further way to distinguish the project. BTW: Why does a transaction rollback it's changes after a crash? It could reuse the transaction-log from before if all changes are written to the persistent log eventually or am I wrong? Obviously some changes would be lost.

Comment: Well seeing as it's simple, keep it that way, add an admin facility for getting rid of the lock file.

Comment: Hm, do you know some database implementation literature? It seems most systems are doing it a bit different from what I read. I definately want to provide a redo-/undo-operation after a crash. I think I just have to store a transaction-commit entry in the log and then decide if I have to recommit all updates which are still in the log. If the transaction failed before the commit the transaction-log could be simply reused.

Comment: So that's something beside the .lock-file ;-)

Comment: NoSQL means no ACID by design.  If you need ACID, don't use NoSQL.  This is poor design.